# Set password in PostgreSQL

Tags: psql

I am trying to set new password in postgreSQL.But I am getting error like below.
`[root@localhost ~]# sudo -u postgres psql`

```
 could not change directory to "/root"
 Welcome to psql 8.1.23, the PostgreSQL interactive terminal.
  Type:  \copyright for distribution terms
    \h for help with SQL commands
    \? for help with psql commands
    \g or terminate with semicolon to execute query
    \q to quit`postgres=# \password postgres
  Query buffer is empty.
  \p: extra argument "assword" ignored
  \p: extra argument "postgres" ignored`
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.
`ALTER USER postgres WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'password';`

Answer (score 0):

Try this? [Link](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/006201c74b23$17cce130$9b0014ac@wbaus090)
Login to your database and use the `ALTER USER Postgres WITH PASSWORD '<newpassword>';` command.

Answer (score 0):

Highly recommended to avoid ever using the `ALTER USER Postgres WITH PASSWORD...` syntax as there is a possibility whatever password you submit will be saved forever in your on disk logs.

Whenever possible, the best way to do it is through an interactive psql CL like so:

psql=# `\password user_name`

If you cannot do that, consider using SCRAM-SHA-256 authentication and the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69480184/9819342).